# Add external event handler to WPF component in C#/ Xaml?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, event-handling

Assume we have a button declared in XML :

```
<button x:Class="A" Content="click me" Name="button" />
```

And in the accompanying class A we have

```
public partial class A {
   BHandler b = new BHandler();
}
```

and the class BHandler consits of:

```
public class BHandler {
   clickHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs){
      Console.WriteLine("button clicked!");
   }
}
```

My question is: Is it possible to register the event handler in b directly to the button, by something like:

```
Click="b.clickHandler"
```

rather than having the event handler in the partial C# class that accompanies the AXML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can for example use some kind of MVVM frameworks as for example [Caliburn Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/). With this one you can just have the function implemented in the view model and have it bound autoamtically by naming convention.

Comment: There is nothing in .NET to enable one to do such a simple thing as organise large classes into separate classes?

Comment: @Tom yes there is but you have to do some coding effort. Looking at the code inside Calibur can ispire you if you want to write a custom MVVM engine.